# Maven ear plugin not picking up ibm-application-bnd.xmi

Tags: java, jenkins, websphere, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I am triggering build from JENKINS but after getting EAR i am not able to get ibm-application-bnd.xmi under META-INF folder. Below is my pom.xml file

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <modules>
                <webModule>
                        <groupId>ABC</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ABCWeb</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/ABCSetup</contextRoot>
                </webModule>
                </modules>
                <manifestFile>${basedir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next:

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <modules>
            <webModule>
                    <groupId>ABC</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ABCWeb</artifactId>
                    <contextRoot>/ABCSetup</contextRoot>
            </webModule>
            </modules>
            <earSourceDirectory>${basedir}</earSourceDirectory>
            <earSourceIncludes>**/META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xmi</earSourceIncludes>
            <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Explanation:

- earSourceDirectory: Single directory for extra files to include in the EAR. Default value is: ${basedir}/src/main/application. We change it to / so we can access the folder META-INF.
- earSourceIncludes: We include the extra XML file.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!It worked but now under EAR I am getting one new folder named as 'target' and under that I am getting some more folders 'classes' and 'ABCEAR->META-INF and target'. Could you please suggest me on the same that why are these folders getting created?

Comment: @user1782009 I think the problem is generateApplicationXml, probably it is generating the application.xml in the new path. Could you check changing it to false?

Comment: Then dont you think it will not generate application.xml itself?

Comment: @user1782009 It's just to verify that this tag is generating that new folder. In that case maybe a solution is to include the application.xml manually as the other xml (if your project allow you to do it), or move your ibm-application-bnd.xmi  to an accesible path into the default earSourceDirectory.

Comment: My build got failed when i changed its value to false getting error: META-INF/application.xml does not exist. Should i include xml also like we included xmi file?

Comment: Yes, you can try with `<earSourceIncludes>**/META-INF/*.xmi</earSourceIncludes>` if you have only those 2 XML, or if you want to include every XML in the META-INF folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32262/discussion-between-user1782009-and-maqjav)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rational Application Developer (RAD) v8.5.1/v9.0 or higher or WebSphere Developer Tools (WDT) V8.5/8.5.5 or higher the help explains more on that since RAD 8.5.1 introduced Maven support which got improved with RAD 9.0.

You can configure RAD/WDT to follow the standard Maven directory structure by adjusting the preferences:
[RAD 8.5 help: Setting preferences](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.maven.doc/topics/prefs.html).

Also, there are more topics in the help, e.g.
[RAD 8.5 help: Recommended POM entries for projects targeting WebSphere® Application Server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.maven.doc/topics/pom_entries_for_was.html).

A Youtube video provides step-by-step guidance
Youtube: Using Maven Integration Tools in IBM Rational Application Developer, Part 1 & Part 2.

For pre-RAD 8.5.1 you can refer to the Whitepaper on the RAD Wiki.